# async attribute in script tag in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, asynchronous

I'm trying to test the following code in Firefox 13.0.1, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercise 1</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" async src="example1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async src="example4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="example3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

//example1.js:

```
alert("I'm the example 1");
```

//example3.js

```
alert("I'm the example 3");
```

//example4.js

```
alert("I'm the example 4");
```

When I open the file which contains the above html code, the following occurs:

**I EDIT THE PROCESS I FOLLOW**

1. In first place, the script "example3.js" is executed, and then a pop-up with the text "I'm the example 3" appears. Afterwards, I click on OK button inside the pop-up window.
2. In second place, the script "example4.js" is executed, and then a pop-up with the text "I'm the example 4" appears. Afterwards, I click on OK button inside the pop-up window.
3. In third place, the script "example1.js" is executed, and then a pop-up with the text "I'm the example 1" appears. Afterwards, I click on OK button inside the pop-up window.
4. And finally, the body content should be displayed (he paragraph with the text "Hello World"), but it doesn't in Firefox, but in Chrome. In Firefox, the page load doesn't stop.

If I open Firebug in Firefox after last script was executed, I realize that the browser does not receive the body element.

[image]

I don't know if my code is correct or is a bug from Firefox.

Thank you.

Comment: That's why it is a good practice to put your js at the bottom of the page :) I believe the alert might block the thread (so it will only show once all three are clicked)

Comment: In Chrome, this above example works correctly, but it doesn't in Firefox.
In Firefox, when the last script (example1.js) is executed, then I click on OK button inside the pop-up window which contains the alert message, and then the content inside the body element should be displayed, but it doesn't.
As @flaviotsf said, I think the last script executed blocks the main thread, but it doesn't happen in Chrome, only in Firefox.

Comment: If you use console.log('I am 1');  instead of alert it does work. So I suppose you cannot use any code that does document.write in async scripts AND code that might block the UI thread (like alerts). Haven't seen this anywhere in the W3C docs though.

Comment: Thanks for your response flaviots.
I made up the above example by myself, so it is not in another place.
I didn't know that an alert message might block the UI thread. I thought that once I clicked on OK button inside the alert pop-up, the UI thread was unblocked.
Anyway, I still don't understand why it works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Minimal example to reproduce: async script with alert, then any sync script (not only in head) breaks loading/parsing of the following part of the document. FF14 is affected too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an already reported bug in firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692754